# Tab is conflicting intellisense and snippets in vs code

Tags: autocomplete, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I want to use a 'for' snippet for example. I write for and press tab twice so it autocompletes to the whole for loop and selects the counter so I can change it. I change that and then press tab to go to next variable(the one 'counter < [here]' in the condition statement). Then the problem is i write 'arr' and it autocompletes to something like 'ANGLE_instanced_arrays'. **I want to just write 'arr' then press tab to go to next variable in the loop, BUT if I press tab it autocompletes.** Any solutions?

Comment: Such an annoying problem. The only solution that worked for me was pressing esc whenever the auto complete showed up while in snippet mode.

Answer (score 25):

I created an account specifically to answer this question because it's such an annoying problem :)

Add the following to your `keybindings.json`:

```
{"key": "tab", "command": "-acceptSelectedSuggestion", "when": "editorTextFocus && suggestWidgetVisible"},    
{"key": "tab", "command": "acceptSelectedSuggestion", "when": "editorTextFocus && suggestWidgetVisible && !inSnippetMode" },
```

The first line disables the existing rule, the second line re-enables it unless you're in snippet mode.

Comment: This worked for me. Had to restart vs code to make it work, but once it re-opened, no issues.

Comment: The `when` condition changed in the later VS code and the first line no longer disables the command, I think that the first line of the keybindings snippet should be changed to `  { "key": "tab", "command": "-acceptSelectedSuggestion", "when": "suggestWidgetHasFocusedSuggestion && suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus" },`

Comment: In modern VSCode, you needn't pay attention to the first line. Just open 
 "Preferences: Keyboard Shortcuts", find `acceptSelectedSuggestion`, right click and choose "Change When Expression" and then set it to what Adam says above: `suggestWidgetHasFocusedSuggestion && suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus && !inSnippetMode`

Answer (score 3):

this is my keybindings.json
press tab to go to next variable in the loop
ctrl+p go to the previous one

```
[  
    {   
      "key": "tab",               
      "command": "selectNextSuggestion",  
      "when": "editorTextFocus && suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions && suggestWidgetVisible" },  
    {  
      "key": "ctrl+p",                    
      "command": "selectPrevSuggestion",  
      "when": "editorTextFocus && suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions && suggestWidgetVisible" },  
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically JakeParis's comment to a previous answer is what worked for me.  However it was confusing for me to find the correct key binding in the Keyboard Shortcuts UI, so I figured I could help provide some guidance on that.

I found it was easiest to use the search bar for acceptSelectedSuggestion, then find the line that was currently bound to the Tab key, then right-click and "Change When Expression" like so: `suggestWidgetHasFocusedSuggestion && suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus && !inSnippetMode`

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUtUH.png) of the line in the Keyboard Shortcuts UI. VSCode v1.82

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to disable accepting suggestions on `tab` and to enable pure `tabCompletion`. The respective settings are `"editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": false` and `"editor.tabCompletion": true`. With those settings you can complete snippets, like `for` just with tab (no IntelliSense pop up) and when IntelliSense shows suggestions can be accepted with `enter` only

Comment: I did set it up to exactly that before but still tab is for both. What i found to be working though is using the arrow key to get rid of intellisense then tab to next variable name